# Angular ngClass multiple ternary operator conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

What is the best way to put more than 1 ternary conditional class in angular's `ngClass` directive, where the values are the class-names?

I've tried a few variations on this, but i always get a compiling error:

`ng-class="$index > 2 ? 'l3 m4 s12 medium' : 'l4 m6 s12 medium', true ? 'red':'blue'`

`ng-class="{$index > 2 ? 'l3 m4 s12 medium' : 'l4 m6 s12 medium', true ? 'red':'blue'}`

Answer (score 12):

While I totally agree with @SamuelMS about explicitly displaying your class names...

If you really want to use multiple ternary operators (or are simply curious) you can do so like this:

```
ng-class="($index > 2 ? 'l3 m4 s12 medium' : 'l4 m6 s12 medium') + ' ' + (true ? 'red' : 'blue')"
```

Comment: haha, that's a nice approach. I can definitely see why @SamuelMS approach is better but this is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

My preferred syntax for ng-class is the following, since it is explicit as to which classes you are adding.

```
ng-class={ 'className' : yourConditionHere, 'class2' : anotherConditionHere }
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to see if there is a way to have the class names as the values of the ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on angular 8+ the following should work.

```
[ngClass]="{'css-class' : condition1 === true || condition2 === true }">
```